# link-report in Flash Builder 4.5 does not generate output file

Tags: eclipse, flash, builder

This is ideally something simple I've overlooked in the past several hours of searching, but I can't seem to generate any output when including the "link-report" compiler commands in Flash Builder 4.5.

I've tried several different syntaxes that I've seen online:

`-linkreport filename.xml`
`-link-report=filename.xml`
`-link-report C:\fullpath\filename.xml`
`-link_report filename.xml`

but absolutely nothing gets created when I run, build, or debug the project. =(

Any ideas about what might be causing this? Other application settings perhaps? The project is relatively young and doesn't have many custom settings so I'm thinking it is maybe application or config related?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Turns out this occurs because I'm working in a Flash Professional project (though I've been able to generate size reports in Flex, Flex Mobile, and Actionscript projects). Is there perhaps a way to import whatever framework is needed to generate this size report without changing to a different project type? I am using Flex 4.5 for all the aforementioned projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Flex (mxmlc) compiler from the command-line directly, rather than from Flash Builder (amxmlc if targeting AIR).  For example:

${FLEX_HOME}/bin/mxmlc -size-report=$SIZE_REPORT_OUTPUT_PATH -link-report $LINK_REPORT_OUTPUT_PATH -debug=$IS_DEBUG -load-config $FLEX_CONFIG -source-path $SRC_DIR -define=CONFIG::DEBUG,$IS_DEBUG -define=CONFIG::FLASH_AUTHORING,$IS_FLASH_AUTHORING -define=CONFIG::IS_RELEASE,$IS_RELEASE -- ${TARGET_NAME}.as

(where ${VARIABLE} or $VARIABLE are defined, naturally)

Answer (score 0):

-link-report myLinkReport.xml

That works for me in FlashBuilder 4.7